# Diference between type script class initialisation and angular component class initialisation

Tags: angular, typescript

I need help understanding the difference between initializing a typescript class and a angular component class.

Here is class A

```
export class A {
    constructor(param) {
    }
}
```

And this is angular component B

```
@Component({
  selector: 'B'
})
export class B {
    constructor(param) {
    }
}
```

Whats the main diference between initializing the 2 classes, can i use :

```
new A("foo");
```

like i use:

```
new B("foo");
```

Is this a good idea? 
Can the injection handle this?

Comment: You don't initialise the component class yourself. Angular does that. But if you insist, I guess you can. Then my question is why would you want to initialise it yourself?

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically create an instance of a component and add it to a template/view?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky exactly, im thinking about merging controller and template into a single component for better readability.

Comment: Then you need to look at the dynamic component loader https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader . You still wouldn’t manually instantiate a @Component() with that though.